# Value passing from one xib to another is not working in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 2 classes with xib files (not in storyboard). when i pass a value from one class to another it always worked before Xcode 5. But now its not working on Xcode 5. I am passing the value from TimeZoneViewController to SignUpViewController as following:

```
NSLog(@"value: %@",cell.textLabel.text); 
SignUpViewController *signUp = [[SignUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
[signUp.timeZoneLabel setText:cell.textLabel.text];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
```

The log is showing the value but after SignUpViewController appears it shows nothing in the "timeZoneLabel". Where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to switch line 4->3 so [signUp.timeZoneLabel setText:cell.textLabel.text]; and then [pushviewcontroller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will navigate you to next screen before setting the value of `timeZoneLabel`. So, you should swap your 3rd line with 4th one to set the text of `timeZoneLabel` first and then to navigate to the `SignUpViewController`.

**Use this Code :**

```
NSLog(@"value: %@",cell.textLabel.text); 
SignUpViewController *signUp = [[SignUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
[signUp.timeZoneLabel setText:cell.textLabel.text];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
```

---

**Update :**

1) Create a property in `SignUpViewController`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * strTimeZoneLabel;
```

2) In first view controller, set that property value.

```
NSLog(@"value: %@",cell.textLabel.text); 
SignUpViewController *signUp = [[SignUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
signUp.strTimeZoneLabel = cell.textLabel.text;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
```

3) In `-viewDidLoad` of `SignUpViewController`, set the text of `timeZoneLabel` :

```
self.timeZoneLabel.text = self.strTimeZoneLabel;
```

Comment: @Leo : Try that **Update** part.

Answer (score 1):

`SignUpViewController`'s view is not loaded to memory from xib, so `signUp.timeZoneLabel == nil`. Use controller property to send value:

```
signUp.timeZoneLabelText = cell.textLabel.text;
```

Here is your property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * timeZoneLabelText;
```

And here is implementation method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.timeZoneLabel setText:self.timeZoneLabelText];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code adding a NSString and update like this :

OtherView.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myText;
```

OtherView.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.timeZoneLabel setText:self.myText];
}
```

Pass data :

```
NSLog(@"value: %@",cell.textLabel.text); 
SignUpViewController *signUp = [[SignUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
[signUp.myText setText:cell.textLabel.text];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the label text of another view controller so you have to pass string value from one class to another class and assign this string value to label in signupviewcontroller's viewDidLoad method.

**Like Below Code**

**In SignUpViewController.h File**

```
@property (nonautomic, retain) NSString *strTimeZone;
@property (nonautomic, retain) UILabel *lblTimeZone;
```

**In SignUpViewController.m File**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.lblTimeZone.text = strTimeZone;
}
```

**In firstviewcontroller File from where you want to push another class**

```
NSLog(@"value: %@",cell.textLabel.text); 
SignUpViewController *signUp = [[SignUpViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil];
signUp.strTimeZone = cell.textLabel.text;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
```

try like this your problem will solved

Comment: same answer as me but it's preferable to refresh in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad.